# Can't add a Hometown Location to profile because Facebook says it doesn't exist

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add the name of the village where I was born in the Hometown field (timeline page on Facebook) and the system doesn't recognize the name so I can't add it.

I read something about adding a location using a smart phone but I don't have a smart phone. Is there any other ways?